# Redirecting printf C++ console output to C#

Tags: c#, c++, redirect

This is my method which is called when I click on a button in my C# GUI program. It launches a very simple C++ console program that does nothing but prints out a line every second in a never ending loop.

```
private static Process process;

private void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "SimpleTest.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

This is the method to handle any output data received:

```
private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
}
```

I do not see any output in my C# debug output...
But if i change the printf to std::cout, it will show the redirected message.

I am thinking if there's any way to show those statements using printf ?

FYI: my c++ code **[EDITED working version]**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int i = 0;

for(;;)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    i++;
    // this version of printf with fflush will work
    printf("The current value of i is %d\n", i);
    fflush(stdout);

    // this version of cout will also work
    //std::cout << "the current value of i is " << i << std::endl;
}

printf("Program exit\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you let the C++ program run long enough for `stdout`'s internal buffer to fill up and get flushed? I don't know offhand what the default buffer size is on Windows; it might be 4k or thereabouts. If the answer to this question is "no" or "huh?", try making the sleep shorter and the message longer, run the program for at least several seconds, and see whether after a while the C# program suddenly does see a ton of output all at once.

Comment: Are you sure about process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;?

Comment: If it does, then your problem is that writes to `stdout` get buffered; you're supposed to be able to make it line-buffered (i.e., output actually gets written out every newline) but I don't think the Microsoft C runtime supports that; but you can make it unbuffered by calling `setvbuf`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs.aspx or you can write to `stderr` instead of `stdout`; `stderr` is unbuffered.

Comment: Can you show the line you use with `std::cout` that's supposedly working?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg std::cout << "the current value of i is " << i << std::endl;

Comment: @David Brabant. Ops my mistake, that line of code should be = true.

Comment: Your use of `std::endl` not only adds a newline but also flushes the output. For it to work in your C program you have to do `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan, you are right! I ran the program longer and the debug output do show the printf statements...

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, yea the fflush(stdout) solves the issue of long waiting for the buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your inputs!

I think I would change all my printf to std::cout and std::endl for my C++ console program.